# What style/font is this?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know what is the font/style used in this article

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Zagier.pdf

PS: No font information included in the properties of the pdf file (File->Properties->Fonts).

Best regards

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: Type the same introduction sentence in a plain LaTeX file.

Comment: Looking at the maths I'm quite sure it has not been typeset with \LaTeX\ (check $\phi(s)$ in inline and in displaystyle modes). Btw the text font seems to be Times New Roman. Moreover it's a scan so good luck for finding any font info.

Answer (score 1):

The embedded fonts in the (original) PDF Are Helvetica, Code2000 and *Times*:
http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf

To me, it looks like you are looking for the *Times*.

[Document URL corrected]

Comment: What's the relevance of the PDF file?

Comment: Excuse me - I've had the wron URL in my clippboard. http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf